# Can ContainerResponseFilter stop execution of filter stack

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Can I write a response filter that stops the execution of further filters in the chain?

```
public class MyResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext, ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
        Response response = HttpConnection.getCurrentConnection().getHttpChannel().getResponse();
        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            //stop processing here      
        }
    }
}
```

The ContainerRequestContext has an abort method but the ContainerResponseContext does not.

I want to do this because I use a 3rd party request filter which writes to the response and then throws WebApplicationException, and I don't want the response chain to convert the WebApplicationException into Response and write it again.

Comment: is there any solution for this issue?